# Creating appointments for multiple users in one request

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to use impersonation to create events on multiple user's calendars at the same time.

Is it possible to send a single request with multiple SOAP envelopes with the event details, or do I need to send separate requests for each event that needs to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Impersonation then then answer is no because impersonation is set at the envelope level you need multiple request. EWS allows batching but these requests are batched within one envelope and hence one security context. If you used a Service Account that had been granted access to all the mailboxes you where trying to access then it would be possible.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks. I had a slightly related question - is it possible to authenticate as a service account using NTLM/Kerberos when the currently logged in user is not the service account? 

For example, User A is running the application, and triggers an event that causes User B to create an event on User C's calendar. User B has impersonation privileges over User C's account.

Comment: Sure if you have UserB credentials then you just set that in whatever class your using eg httpwebrequest credentials etc. Its all dependant on the client library your using (and that fact you actually have UserB credentials).

Comment: I will have access to User B's credentials, so that's good news. Thanks once again!